# Matrix, orthogonal and cross product

Tags: matrices, cross-product

Let A be ortogonal $3\times3$ matrix. How do I show that
$$A(v\times w)=(\det A)(Av\times Aw)$$

Here \times is crossproduct and v and w are $3$-dim vector.

Comment: Use the $ sign to encapsulate your tex

Comment: If $A$ is orthogonal then $\det(A)=\pm1 \ \ $, $+1$ for rotation and $-1$ for reflection. Both operations preserve length of vectors and angles between them, reflection however changes the order for $v,w, v \times w$ from    the right handed to the left handed frame.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't understand it.
Can you please give a more detalied answer and try to write out the above where you decribe in which step you use what you say above.

Answer (score 0):

Restate the claim as $A^T(Av\times Aw)=(\det A)(v\times w)$. The $i$th component of the left-hand side is$$A_{ij}^T\epsilon_{jkl}(Av)_k(Aw)_l=\epsilon_{jkl}A_{ji}A_{km}A_{ln}v_mw_n=(\det A)\epsilon_{imn}v_mv_n,$$which is the $i$th component of the right-hand side.